# Android SQLite foreign key for 2 tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating Android application, and now I am stuck about proper DB design.

I have 3 tables in my local sqlite db:

```
BOXES
id
title
```

```
NOTES
id
title
content
```

```
BOXES_NOTES
id
box_id
element_id
type
```

Element ID is id for *NOTES.id* or *BOXES.id* and now I want to make it as foreign key, so when I delete entry in **BOXES** or **NOTES**, I want to update **BOXES_NOTES** table appropriately. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE BOXES_NOTES(
ID .... REFERENCES NOTES(ID) ON DELETE /*your constraint*/
BOX_ID ... REFERENCES BOXES(ID) ON DELETE /*your constraint*/
... )
```

After ON DELETE you can add:

`NO ACTION` -> You can't delete a box row if there's at least one id into box_notes

`CASCADE` -> If you delete a box row all boxes_notes rows with that id will be deleted

`SET NULL` -> If you delete a box row all boxes_notes rows with that id will be set to null (if possible)

What said for ON DELETE is also valid for ON UPDATE.

Remember that using SQLite you have to abilitate foreign keys control. I suggest you to use a SQLiteOpenHelper and override the onOpen method like that:

```
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            // Enable foreign key constraints
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, how can I make element_id to reference to id in notes or id in boxes?

Comment: Please take into account that "box_id" is id of box which has couple of elements (like folder with files). Each box can contain other boxes or notes and I want to remove entry from BOXES_NOTES when any element is deleted (if box with elements is deleted - remove all entries with that box id, if element (box or note in other box) is deleted - remove only entry with that element_id)

Answer (score 0):

```
[box_id] INTEGER CONSTRAINT [box_ref] REFERENCES [BOXES]([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
[element_id] INTEGER CONSTRAINT [notes_ref] REFERENCES [NOTES]([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
```

since we have cascade delete in both box_id and element_id, any entry in box or in notes deleted will cascade delete entry in this table

suggestion - use proper naming convention
instead of element_id name it notes__id (double underscore normally used to name foreign keys

for all these to work in sqlite one important thing is that we have to enable foreign key constraint at database level which is by default disabled in android

to enable foreign key constraint do the below 
**db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");**

Comment: Thanks for your response, but please look into comment in first post: element_id can be either box_id or note_id (so it can reference to ID in **BOXES** table or **NOTES** table).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I redesigned DB a little bit, so now I have only 2 tables:

```
BOXES
id
title
box_id
```

```
NOTES
id
title
content
box_id
```

Thank you all for answers.